# php html - input tag is displayed before php although php is written first

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

i wrote a form with some php loop to insert array and numbers

a form inside a table with tr td to get fixed width

php array within form, then for loops with html tr td

at the end of the form, <input>

```
<table>
<form method='post'>

<?php
$row=array(
'databaseName',
'tableName',
'nColumns',
'columnName',
'dataType',
'dataSize',
'null',
'indexing');

for($k=0; $k<=7; $k++){
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row[$k]; ?></td>
<td><input name='<?php echo $row[$k]; ?>' type='text'>
</input></td></tr>

<?php if($k==2){ ?>
<tr>
<td>Number of Columns</td>
<td><select onchange='nColumns()'>

<?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){ ?>
<option id='<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></td></tr><?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<input name='submit' type='submit'></input>
</form></table>
```

but the input is displayed first before php loops. why? and how do i make the submit button to be at the bottom?

Comment: You can not nest a form into a table like that. Either the form must go around the whole table, or the form must be contained in one single table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because your submit button is outside the table structure, specifically outside the `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Try the below code:

```
<form method='post'>
    <table>

        //Your code

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name='submit' type='submit'></input>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: That kind of nesting of form into table is still not correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. table need to in the form.
2. recommended to place the submit button outside the table

   ```
    <form method='post'>
    <table>
        <?php
        $row = array(
            'databaseName',
            'tableName',
            'nColumns',
            'columnName',
            'dataType',
            'dataSize',
            'null',
            'indexing'
        );
        for ($k = 0; $k <= 7; $k++) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row[$k]; ?></td>
                <td><input name='<?php echo $row[$k]; ?>' type='text'>
                    </input></td>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($k == 2) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number of Columns</td>
                    <td><select onchange='nColumns()'>

                            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) { ?>
                                <option id='<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select></td>
                </tr><?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
    <input name='submit' type='submit'></input>
   ```